# im having problems parsing nested json with php

Tags: php, json

Json Data

```
{
"response": 
{
    "status": 
    {
        "version": "4.2",
        "code":             ,
        "message": "Success"
    },
    "songs": 
    [
        {
            "artist_id": "ARYUDWF12F2B89BB33",
            "artist_name": "The Weeknd",
            "id": "SOMVZDS14DDE5909E7",
            "song_hotttnesss": 0.721485,
            "title": "Can't Feel My Face"
        },
        {
            "artist_id": "ARTZYQN13EEEF973E7",
            "artist_name": "Kygo",
            "id": "SOJJAOR14C0CA2A061",
            "song_hotttnesss": 0.698138,
            "title": "Stole the Show"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

My PHP Data

```
<?php 

    $jsondata = file_get_contents("hotsongs.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach($json['songs'] as $song){
        $output .= "<h4>".$song['name']."</h4>";
        $output .= "<h4>".$song['title']."</h4>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: what is your problem? add more details

Comment: Json Is not Valid change "code": , to "code": " ",

Comment: json is not valid - this will break it right away, and when you fix that there is no song property called 'name' also you are not wrapping your output html in <li> elements for your <ul>

Comment: yes i realized it.  i tried to put the correct json but it doesnt allow me. it says too much code.  need to enter more info.    :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("hotsongs.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $output = "<table><tr><th>Artist Name</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
    foreach($json['response']['songs'] as $song){

        $output .='<tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$song['artist_name'].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$song['title'].'</td>';
        $output .='</tr>';

    }
    $output .= "</table>";

    echo $output;
```

Comment: sorry... yay it works.  but can you tell me how i can make it into a table format instead?

Comment: what you want a table from provided json??

Comment: Yes instead of ul lists I would like a table list with the artist_name and title

Comment: thanks so much. it works.   so grateful.   im new to php. dont know how to program. even this code i originally paste was from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ua8oqm_HBSY

Comment: don't forgot to upvote my answer..

Comment: oh i didnt know that i can upvote.  new to stackoverflow.  just did it.   :)

Comment: thanks so much again

Answer (score 1):

json format is wrong

```
{
   "response": 
 {
 "status": 
  {
    "version": "4.2",
    "code": "",//check here on your code
    "message": "Success"
 },
  "songs": 
  [
    {
        "artist_id": "ARYUDWF12F2B89BB33",
        "artist_name": "The Weeknd",
        "id": "SOMVZDS14DDE5909E7",
        "song_hotttnesss": 0.721485,
        "title": "Can't Feel My Face"
    },
    {
        "artist_id": "ARTZYQN13EEEF973E7",
        "artist_name": "Kygo",
        "id": "SOJJAOR14C0CA2A061",
        "song_hotttnesss": 0.698138,
        "title": "Stole the Show"
      }
   ]
  }
  }
```

Comment: Yes I tried to paste correct json but it doesn't let me. Says I have too much code.  Doesn't allow me

Answer (score 1):

Corrections:

1) Your `code` attribute does not have any value.

It should be at least blank (`""`).

That is being considered as error and your JSON is incorrectly formatted.

2) Correct

```
foreach($json['songs'] as $song){
```

To:

```
foreach($json['response']['songs'] as $song){
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have wrongly pasted the wrong json. By the way how did you fix my question? When I tried to paste the correct json it says in too much code. Quite annoying

Answer (score 0):

Use `$json['response']['songs']` while looping

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("hotsongs.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach($json['response']['songs'] as $song){

$output .= "<h4>".$song['name']."</h4>";
$output .= "<h4>".$song['title']."</h4>";

}
$output .= "</ul>";


print_r($output);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the foreach into a table list instead?  Basically one table with lists of artist and name